# Ember app not posting to server with Ember Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, server, ember-data

I am trying to connect my ember app to a node server on the backend.  Right now, I have a sign up and login form and when the user submits either form it will go through an authentication process setup in node using Passport.  However when the submit button is pressed it just reloads the current page and doesn't even send a HTTP post request.  Any ideas on why this is happening/ how to fix it?

Here is my adapter:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({  
    host: 'http://localhost:8080'
});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

Here is my sign up controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
    new: function() {
      console.log('creating new user...');

      var model = this.get('user');

      user = this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
        title: model.get('title'),
        password: model.get('password')
      });
      user.save().then(function(data) {
        // Clear the form.
        Ember.$(':input').val('');
      });
    },
  }
});
```

Here is my model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Here is the form:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Signup</h1>
</div>

<form>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        {{input value=username type="text" placeholder="Username"}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        {{input value=password type="password" placeholder="Password"}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        {{input class="button" type="submit" value="Signup"}}
      </div>
    </div>



</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your form, it sounds like you are doing a post with the form and not handling the action correctly.

Comment: Just added the form code @Knownasilya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so there seems to be a few issues here.

First, looking at the controller that you posted, there are a few things that don't look right:

- The `user` variable is never declared
- You try to `get` the `user` property from the controller, but it is never defined
- You try to clear the form using `Ember.$(':input').val('');` which doesn't really make any sense, if the inputs are bound to the template.

We'll start by cleaning up the template, which will drive the improvements to the controller:

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <h1>Signup</h1>
</div>

<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
      {{input value=username type="text" placeholder="Username"}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
      {{input value=password type="password" placeholder="Password"}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
      <button class="button" type="submit" {{action 'createUser'}}>Signup</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The major issues seems to be that you're using an `{{input}}` helper for the button, which doesn't really make any sense.  The `{{input}}` helper if for inputting text.  We've also moved the action to be bound to the button being clicked instead, which is the behavior that you want.

Now, the controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  // Username for the new user
  username: '',

  // Password for the new user
  password: '',

  actions: {

    // Create a new user
    createUser() {
      const username = this.get('username');
      const password = this.get('password');

      this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
        username,
        password
      }).save()
      .then(() => {
        this.send('clearForm');  // Invokes the `clearForm` action on the controller
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Do some kind of error handling if the creation fails
      });
    },

    // Clear the form
    clearForm() {
      this.set('username', '');
      this.set('password', '');
    }
  }
});
```

Now we have a controller with two properties defined, to hold the username and password for the new user.  They are bound to the input fields in the template, and we manipulate them both get the values out of the template and also to clear them again.

Answer (score 2):

You have a submit button that does a post request by default. You can do the following.

```
<form {{action 'new' on='submit'}}>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        {{input value=user.username type="text" placeholder="Username"}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        {{input value=user.password type="password" placeholder="Password"}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
        <button class="button" type="submit">Signup</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This basically says intercept the submit event and call the action instead.

Note that I also added `user.` to your input values, otherwise you'd get them from your controller as `this.get('username')`, etc.

Comment: I just added that into the code and the same thing is still happening.  Are there any other things that I need to do to make this work? @Knownasilya

Comment: Just added the 'user.' to the input values and it still spitting back the same errors.  Do I need to change the controller code at all or anything else to get this to work? @knownasilya